# Final cut pro custom shares to my scriptable application which is not responded

Tags: objective-c, macos, share, scriptable, finalcut

I'm trying to develop osx application that is respond final cut pro custom share.

[image: final cut pro custom share to my application]

I have been looking for references a lot for 2 weeks. And I did followings.

- Createed sdef  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/exchanging_content_and_metadata_with_final_cut_pro/receiving_media_and_data_through_a_custom_share_destination/creating_scripting_definitions_for_custom_share_destinations?changes=_2_1__8
- Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>OSAScriptingDefinition</key>
<string>pairs.sdef</string>
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>hello</string>
<key>com.apple.proapps.MediaAssetProtocol</key>
<dict>
</dict>
```

- Implemented everything need and passed test apple script code from editor

```
tell application "My Application"
    make new asset with properties ¬
        {name:"MyNewAsset", |metadata|:{|com.apple.proapps.share.episodeID|:"MyNewEpisode"}, dataoptions:{|availableMetadataSets|:{"Camera View", "General View"}}}
    set newAsset to result
    set theLocation to location info of newAsset
end tell

Result : 
{folder:file "Macintosh HD:Users:handsome:Documents:gemiso"}
```

Then, I added custom share destination in final cut pro and point to my application
[image]

I executed my application with xcode debug mode.

I click Final Cut Pro > File > Share > 'my application'

But my application didn't respond.

I lost way. please help me

Comment: Omg, I archived, distributed(devleopment), moved it to /Applications, then rebooted my computer. Finally final cut pro x recognized my application. But not in xcode, in application.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to implement FCP share destination in my app for over a month now. I've tried to follow the official docs and looked everywhere, but I can't figure out how to do it. I'm desperately looking for an example project to use as a reference. If you still have this project of yours, I would be very grateful if you could share some of the code with me in some way. Sorry to bother you here, but I have lost hope. 

Thanks in a advance if you can help me in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I found way.

Reason why my application did not respond is because of 2 conditions.

1. packaged and provisioning should be above at least Developer ID(Distribute directly to customers)
2. It should be in application folder